# USB Memory Stick From Scratch

Tags: microcontroller, usb, firmware, usb-host, nand-flash

How can i make USB memory stick from scratch?

As far as i know i need NAND flash memory chip and NAND controller chip. 
Which two should i use, can u recommend something and which firmware should use? Also can i write it myself? I Want to biuld also an USB hub so what are your adivces. What is my starting point?

Thank you in front cause i am really confused at this point :)

Comment: And the point of this would be... ? Why ask us what **you** can write, how would we know ? You're confused because you want everything at once and this is not something you can build easily from separate components. Get an old USB stick, open it and see what is inside. Could you make that ?

Comment: ok, i can do that and that is not problem...i can even make my own pcb borad with al the stuff my old usb have...but what then? I need to load some linux kenrel on it, right?

Comment: Why would you need a linux kernel ? Do you need a kernel ? Do you need an OS ? What do you need ? What you need to do first is educate yourself on the subject. You cannot design this project yourself. Either copy a ready-made design (not a product of which you have no design information) or start with something simpler. You want too much all at once.

Comment: well i dont know do i need kernel..i am searching on internet for that but nowhere is written what is on controller chip? I want to know what is inside of that contoller chip

Comment: Then download the datasheet and see **what you can do** with that controller. What is inside (the actual schematic) is irrelevant to you and also the manufacturer's secret.

Answer (score 2):

*How can i make USB memory stick from scratch?*

The only practical way is to use a USB Flash Drive Controller. Have a look at http://www.siliconmotion.com/A3.2_Features_Detail.php?sn=22

This is quite a complex IC. You could attempt to implement it with a separate processor, NAND controller, USB controller, etc. But you would end up with a PCB about 10cm x 10cm. It's just not worth the effort.

[image]

Comment: Same goes for "make a hub from scratch": there are single-chip hub ICs to use.

Comment: When i connect two same USB in USB Hub and the Hub into PC and connect them so instead showing two 1Gb volumes i have one 2 Gb volume where does that logic happens. Is it PC's host controller in charge. Basicly the idea was to make something like this picture...just give me a sec to figure out how to upload a pic

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/vmri8y.jpg